# Should I use auxiliary here or not?

Tags: grammar

How many dialogue do we have here?

How many dialogue we have here?

As far as I'm concerned in the answer we didn't have subject we should use  auxiliary  here.

Answer (score 4):

Your guess is correct. We need the *do* in the sentence to make a valid question form.

But since we are asking *How many,* we will use the plural form of the noun *dialogues.*

> *How many dialogues do we have here?*

The grammatical concept is often described under the term *do-support.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support